# What is the resultant unit type of some VW value + some REM value?

Tags: css, responsive, fluid-layout, typography

In considering:

```
clamp(1.25rem, 2.5vw + 1rem, 2.5rem);
```

which I assume to be equivalent to:

```
clamp(1.25rem, calc(2.5vw + 1rem), 2.5rem);
```

What is the resultant unit-type of the middle calc expression?

I understand that with the clamp function, in particular respect to the middle target value- if only screen-relative units are used Accessibility concerns arise, as the text will no longer respond to magnification. So we introduce the addition of REM units, and this produces behind-the-scenes some value which now responds to zooming attempts.

But that produced/computed value- is it in REMs or, pixels, etc?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question as the font-size setting is kept at that formula so if any of its constituent parts changes in value the size is recalculated. If you inspect the computed value though the font-size will always be given in px, and you can see in your browser's inspect facility how it changes as you change the viewport. Is there an effect on magnification? Could you explain more what you have observed that gives a problem? I don't see one.

Comment: @AHaworth No problem at present. I was curious as to why, if as you say in the devtools the font-size is always when all is said and done computed into px, why magnification of that final value proves problematic. As in, if we end up at the same final unit type no matter the path taken to get there(a computed px value; using screen-relative units or screen-relative units + font-relative units), then why would there be a need to use REMs in the clamp function at all? The ultimate value is pixels, regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's complicated.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#calc-computed-value)

From the linked spec we see that the computed value of your clamp expression will resolve to a single value, because it can be so resolved. But had it contained percentages, or something else that depended on layout, then the computed value might be the expression, or a simplified version of the expression, and the single value won't be obtained until the used value is determined.

The actual unit of the single value is not determined. However, for *serialization* (as you'd see in the browser's dev tools for example). [lengths are represented in pixels](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#ref-for-absolute-length). Not all calculations are represented in pixels though. Angles, for example, calculating on degrees and radians and turns, will be represented in degrees. Other types of values have other [canonical units](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#canonical-unit).

Comment: Thank you! This provided the insight I was looking for, specifically that within this context the final units are pixels.